# No HTML5 audio on (iOS8) device in cordova/phonegap app

Tags: ios, cordova, ios-simulator, html5-audio

I have a cordova app that was using media plugin for audio playback, but then it got broken with iOS8, because of this [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7517). I thought I will just use HTML5 audio (concretely audio5.js) as a workaround. Everything works nice in the simulator but when tested on the iPad, there is no sound. There is also no error reported it just looks as the sound is turned off.

For the testing I made cordova app with just plain example from the audio5.js [github](https://github.com/zohararad/audio5js) repository and I also tried with examples from two similar libraries audio.js and sound.js. 
The result is the same, examples work in simulator and also from the web on mobile Safari on the device, but on the device inside cordova there is no sound.

I also included this two lines in the config.xml file

```
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true"/>
<preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false"/>
```

without success.

I'm using cordova cli version: 3.6.3-0.2.13

**EDIT:**

It seems that iOS update 8.1.2 resolved original problem [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7517), so I recomend using Media plugin for audio on iOS .

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? I'm experiencing something similar.

Comment: I started to experiment with the plugin that is described here [link](http://devgirl.org/2014/11/10/boost-your-ios-8-mobile-app-performance-with-wkwebview/) , but I haven't managed to make it work yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get sound on the device with WKWebView which is at the moment not yet available in core cordova because there are some bugs. A workaround is a WKWebView plugin that is described by DevGirl [here](http://devgirl.org/2014/11/10/boost-your-ios-8-mobile-app-performance-with-wkwebview/). 
Using WKWebView created a problem for audio5.js when playing multiple sounds one after another where next sound is triggered by play "ended" of previous sound. I couldn't fix the issue, so I decided to try soundmanager2.js which worked with out the problem.

I still have a problem with playing sounds which are not inside www directory (sounds are downloaded to the device and are not included with the app), but this is I think another issue not related to the this question.